# Winform control checkbox location changes in runtime when i used in WPF?

Tags: .net, wpf, visual-studio, c#-4.0

I have winform control library in my application. There is one checkbox at right bottom of panel control.
(i have set checkbox location manually.).Whenever i use winform library in WPF, it looks good in Windows 7 classic theme but checkbox location get changed automatically in
Windows 7 basic theme. I debugged the code & found that checkbox locaton changed runtime in WPF. Checkbox location changed runtime in WPF.
Both application i.e. Winform and WPF have 4.0 framework.
The problem occurs only in windows 7 basic theme.

Not getting what to do?

Please suggest, if you can
Will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you show XAML of your WPF window?

Comment: Use WPF checkbox instead